# WebGL Three.js diagnostic tools

Tags: javascript, three.js

I entered a question yesterday and I'd like to change tactics while still keeping the previous thread alive, if possible.  (The previous question was concerning variable frame rates in Three.js.)

Rather than address the question directly, I'd like to know what WebGL/Three.js developers use to diagnose their code (to find performance bottlenecks specifically).

I'm starting a large-ish, long-term project and I assume I'll run into all sorts of problems along the way.  How to we peer behind the curtain?

I saw a related question and came to WebGL-Inspector, which I will look into.  Just looking for all the options.  I'm willing to spend money to get professional diagnostic tools.  Whatever it takes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, sir.

I use:

- chrome javascript profiler
- chrome canvas inspection (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/)
- occasionally try tools like webgl-inspector but it doesn't seem quite as good as chrome's canvas inspector

Also:

- standard profiling techniques for javascript, use unminified code to see what's going on everywhere during profiling
- basic sanity checks: for frame rate issues, make sure your frame flipping run loop code is up to snuff. Standard practice is using requestAnimationFrame.
- make sure your canvas is not being stretched

I have not yet tried applying a pure desktop opengl type of debugger (nvidia nsight, for example) to webgl running inside the browser.

Comment: Thanks, man!  Nice to hear from you.  I'm heading up that-a-ways at the end of April.  You going to be around?

Comment: Yep! Should be around. Looking forward to it!